# How to make a bash command executable from any directory in Windows?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have made a few bash scripts that I have saved to individual folders. I have Windows 10. The scripts have functions that executes commands in bash. I am now able to execute these .sh scripts from any directory, since I have added the folders they are saved in to the path variable. But I want to make it even easier for me, and be able to only have to type the function in the bash console to execute the command.

This is an example of one of the scripts. It is saved as file_lister.sh. I am able to run this by typing "file_lister.sh" but I want to run it by only typing the function name in the script, which is "list_files". How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

function list_files(){
    cp C:/Users/jmell/OneDrive/projects/file_lister/file_lister.py file_lister.py
    python file_lister.py
    cwd=$(pwd)
    if [ $cwd != "/c/Users/jmell/OneDrive/projects/file_lister" ]
    then
        rm file_lister.py
    fi
}

list_files
```

Comment: You do realize that you can run a script not in your current directory by giving the full path? This whole copying and deleting thing is massive overkill.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you source all of your scripts (e.g. in your `.bashrc` file), the functions won't be defined. However, your function is doing a lot of extra work that it really shouldn't be. The example script can be reduced to

```
#!/bin/bash
python C:/Users/jmell/OneDrive/projects/file_lister/file_lister.py
```

Better, yet, keep in mind that the shebang line is read and stripped off by the shell. It specifies the interpreter to use. Instead of creating a wrapper script, add the following line to `file_lister.py`:

```
#!/path/to/python
```

At that point, I'd also recommend renaming `file_lister.py` to just `file_lister`.